# Python win32com insert word object into Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

Excel error: "Document not saved" when trying to insert multiple objects into excel file.  Works for zip and .mpp file extensions, but not working with .doc and .docx file types. Once inserted, the object shows a white unknown file image and simply says EMBED("Document","").  However, when I insert manually these docs I have no problems and they display as Word doc icon.  Any Suggestions?

```
import win32com.client as win32
xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Visible = 1
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('BlankTemplate.xlsx')  #New Excel file that is blank
xl.DisplayAlerts = False
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
dest_cell = ws.Range('C5')
obj = ws.OLEObjects()
```

obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename='Approval.zip',Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=False,Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=50,Height=50)
obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename='Final.docx',Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=True,Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=50,Height=50)
obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename='Release.doc',Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=True,Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=50,Height=50)
obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename='Platform.mpp',Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=False,Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=50,Height=50)

```
wb.SaveAs('ProjectDetailsAttachments.xlsx')
xl.DisplayAlerts = True
xl.Application.Quit()
xl.Visible = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!!  I recorded a Excel VBA macro in order to see what it uses to insert a word document object and found they have a few additional parameters added, once i added them it works now.

```
wordpath = 'C\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office 14\\WINWORD.EXE'
obj.Add(ClassType=None,Filename='Final.docx',Link=False,DisplayAsIcon=True, \ 
    IconFileName=wordpath,IconIndex=0,IconLabel=Final.docx \ 
    Left=dest_cell.Left, Top=dest_cell.Top,Width=50,Height=50)
```